# answer appearing and dissapearing in javascript number guessing game

Tags: javascript

I have a code that checks if the number input by user is the same as random generated number but for some reason my output appears for a moment and vanishes again. How can I make the output not vanish?
Output:

```
<p id="guesses"></p>
<p id="lastResult"></p>
<p id="lowOrHi"></p>
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1>Guess that number!</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="guessField">Guess nr 1-100</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="guessField" class="input">
        <br><br>
        <button id="guessSubmit" onclick="checkGuess();" class="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p id="guesses"></p>
    <p id="lastResult"></p>
    <p id="lowOrHi"></p>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
console.log("random number generated");
var guesses = document.getElementById("guesses");
var lastResult = document.getElementById("lastResult");
var lowOrHi = document.getElementById("lowOrHi");

var guessSubmit = document.getElementById("guessSubmit");
var guessField = document.getElementById("guessField");
var guessCount = 1;
console.log("guess 1");

function checkGuess() {
    var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
    console.log("userGuess");
    guesses.innerHTML += userGuess + " ";

    if(userGuess == randomNumber) {
        lastResult.innerHTML = "Congradz, you won!";
        lowOrHi.innerHTML = "";
        console.log("won");
    } else {
        lastResult.innerHTML = "This is NOT correct!";
        console.log("wrong");
        if(userGuess < randomNumber) {
            lowOrHi.innerHTML = "Your guess is too low!";
            console.log("too low");
        } else if(userGuess > randomNumber) {
            lowOrHi.innerHTML = "Your guess is too high";
            console.log("too high")
        }
    }
    guessCount++;
    guessField.value = "";
}
```

Comment: Is your form submitting? Do you see a refresh of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you submit the form hence refreshing the page. One solution is to change `form tag` to `div tag`

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
console.log("random number generated");
var guesses = document.getElementById("guesses");
var lastResult = document.getElementById("lastResult");
var lowOrHi = document.getElementById("lowOrHi");

var guessSubmit = document.getElementById("guessSubmit");
var guessField = document.getElementById("guessField");
var guessCount = 1;
console.log("guess 1");

function checkGuess() {
    var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
    console.log("userGuess");
    guesses.innerHTML += userGuess + " ";

    if(userGuess == randomNumber) {
        lastResult.innerHTML = "Congradz, you won!";
        lowOrHi.innerHTML = "";
        console.log("won");
    } else {
        lastResult.innerHTML = "This is NOT correct!";
        console.log("wrong");
        if(userGuess < randomNumber) {
            lowOrHi.innerHTML = "Your guess is too low!";
            console.log("too low");
        } else if(userGuess > randomNumber) {
            lowOrHi.innerHTML = "Your guess is too high";
            console.log("too high")
        }
    }
    guessCount++;
    guessField.value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1>Guess that number!</h1>
    <div>
        <label for="guessField">Guess nr 1-100</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="guessField" class="input">
        <br><br>
        <button id="guessSubmit" onclick="checkGuess();" class="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <p id="guesses"></p>
    <p id="lastResult"></p>
    <p id="lowOrHi"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 1):

`submit` buttons submit. `return false;`, or pass in the `eventObject` and `eventObject.preventDefault()` at the bottom of `checkGuess`. Note that the later is the only kind that will work if using `Element.addEventListener(function(eventObj){ eventObj.preventDefault()})`.